# setValue or setFormula not working

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

The debugger seems to show me all the variables setting correctly.
Not really sure why its not pasting the values correctly.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var budgetsheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

  var lastcol = budgetsheet.getLastColumn();
  var prevrange = budgetsheet.getRange(4, lastcol);
  var prevdate = budgetsheet.getRange(4, lastcol).getValue();
  var mydateformula = "=" + prevrange.getA1Notation() + "+7";
  var futurerange = budgetsheet.getRange(4, lastcol +1);

  //insert the columns and copy the fomatting
  budgetsheet.insertColumnsAfter(lastcol, 1);

  //paste the date as a value
  futurerange.setFormula(mydateformula); //neither setValue or setFormula seem to work
```

[image: variables]

Comment: I've tested a variation of your code, and looked at it, and as far as the code goes, it seems to me that it should work.  So, I'm guessing it's not the code.  But I'm not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: It worked for me too. Try changing your date format and see if that works.

Comment: I don't know what was happening, but this code eventually worked. Thanks for checking my sanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to function. Perhaps a cache issue.